# looping through a precise list of sheets in Excel with VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro for consolidating many sheets in a big one.
I loop through all the sheets that have the same structure and i avoid some other sheets in this way:

```
For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets


        If IsError(Application.Match(sh.Name, _
                                     Array("Consolidated Pipeline", "Instructions", "Dashboard", "Data"), 0)) Then
        
         'Doing things.

        End If
Next sh
```

Now someone will add more sheets in workbook, and i can't know the names of these new sheets.

the order of the sheet is: Instructions , Dahsboard, Consolidated Pipeline, ---From here--- USA, France, Italy... (others country), ---To Here--- then I have Data (to be avoided).

i have to loop from the fisrt country sheet (USA here) to the last country sheet and avoid every sheet before and after.

how can i achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like:

```
For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets


    If sh.Index > Worksheets("---From Here---").Index And sh.Index < Worksheets("---To Here---").Index Then
    
     'Doing things.

    End If
Next sh
```